# How to programmatically turn GPS on and off in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, geolocation, sensors

So far, to turn on and off the GPS device in Wp7, I do it in  Settings Menu. Wonder If this can be done in code?

Thanks

---------- Update

Sorry for the confusion. Instead of turning GPS on and off, What I really mean is how to turn on and off the LOCATION in the Settings Menu of Wp7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [GPS data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) but you are not able to turn the sensor on or off via your application.

The most you can do in your application is [start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.start%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) the geolocation data acquisition and [stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.stop%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I think I made a wrong statement. It should be how to programmatically turn on and off the LOCATION which is in the Settings Of WP7.

Comment: I stated it in my answer - you can't turn the sensor on or off from inside your application - when you are using the location switch, you are managing the GPS sensor.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is the only way. To inform user how to do it, I use a page to explain what and how.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 apps should not change global settings for the phone.

You should have your own settings page in your app, with it's own toggle for whether or not your app should use the location data.

Then you check your setting before you access the location data.

Why would you want to turn it off globally?

Comment: @JEFFMAPHONE: Assume the user know nothing about location service and how to turn it on /off. The setting page you mentioned is a page with checkboxes. If I check yes to turn on Location, can you programmatically turn on the location service or you will provide text message telling me how and where to set it on? Pls explain

Comment: You make a settings page in your app.  You direct the user to it.  I can't help you any further.

Comment: turn off GPS to save battery