# Can I do enable GPS programmatically from my app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Windows 10 phone application. Can I do it programmatically or not? Windows 7 have no variants, maybe windows 10 mobile have new methods or variants?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically turn GPS on and off in Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858901/how-to-programmatically-turn-gps-on-and-off-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: This answer intended for OS wp7, this actual for wp10 ? Maybe wp10 have new methods?

Comment: Good point, I've removed my close vote. Though I am quite sure you shouldn't be able to do so, you can request location access permission, but you shouldn't be able to turn on/off location service itself. That's what user decides to have or not to have on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But not if the user has disabled GPS on their device.

First you need to enable it.

From msdn site:

1. In Solution Explorer, double-click package.appxmanifest and select
   the Capabilities tab.
2. In the Capabilities list, select the Capabilities tab. This adds the
   Location device capability to the package manifest file.

Then you can request access to the location.
Example from msdn:
Add this using statement:

using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;

And call this method:

var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

Read the documentation here for further details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location